# How to skip tests in Jest without changing tests code?

Tags: jestjs

Ideally, my goal is to skip tests programmatically on the fly, sometimes after a test has finished running depending on its status. This seems, however, impossible based on this issue https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7245.

I've solved this by implementing my custom runner and intercepting results.

Now, I wonder if there's a way to prevent certain tests from running at all. The only option I've found is `testNamePattern`, there I managed to write a negative regex to exclude certain tests from running. This gets ugly when you want to skip 100s of tests, though.

So, to sum up:

1. Is there a better way to skip tests in jest programmatically, except using a custom runner?
2. How can I prevent certain tests from runner based on some external list?